# How to handle minimised app back press?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I am not able to handle this below scenario.
When I go to Activity B from Activity A and minimize the app and open from recent apps, Activity B will open and if I press back on Activity B, Activity A should resume, but in my case the app is closing.

**Activity A**

```
tool_setting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(Activity_A.this,
                        Activity_B.class);
                startActivity(mIntent);
            }
        });
```

After clicking on button, opens Activity B.
On B, I minimize and open app from recent apps, again on B if I press back button on toolbar, app closes instead of resuming Activity A.

Comment: you might be finishing your Activity A while passing intent...can you post code you tried ?

Comment: @Mohit provided my code on button click.

Comment: can you also post the code of back button on toolbar...

Comment: @Mohit made custom toolbar, on that using a button. `tool_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });`

Comment: post your manifest please.

Comment: @David thanks for opening my eyes, **Activity A** had `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` working well now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to take care of your [Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html). Without knowing your code, you might be closing (calling `finish()`) your Activity A.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason that it will happen is if you are calling finish() after startActivity().

Something like:

```
private void startActivityB()
{
    Intent startActivityBIntent = new Intent(mContext, ActivityB.class);
    startActivity(startActivityBIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: No I am not using `finish()`. I have updated my question with the code I am using.

Comment: can you add more of the activity code? onPause, onStop etc.